# Count number of Children in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, children, jcomponent

I have a JPanel, to which I have added an unknown number of JComponents.  How can I count the number of JComponents in that JPanel?

I have looked at the API, but I see no method for retrieving the children so that I can count them.  Is this possible to count the children afterwards?  Or do I have to go back and count the children as I am adding them?

By child, I mean a JComponent on which is from: `myPanel.add(new JComponent())`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind.  It was hiding in the Container API.

```
myPanel.getComponentCount();
```